# Encode with "\u four-hex-digits" in JSON::XS for Perl

Tags: json, perl, utf-8, ascii

I have hashes that include strings with UTF-8 characters, such as:

```
$hash = { text => 'Dragón' };
```

When I encode it to JSON using JSON::XS, I get something like this:

```
{"text":"DragÃ³n"}
```

Which although looks ugly, works, but I would like to get something like this:

```
{"text":"Drag\u00f3n"}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->ascii` will restrict the output to US-ASCII characters.

```
my $json = JSON::XS->new->ascii;

my $text = $json->encode($hash);
```

Comment: Thanks :).  Is there a way to do this with the functional interface?  Or just the object oriented one?

Comment: `encode_json` is just `sub encode_json { JSON::XS->new->utf8->encode($_[0]) }`, so I guess you want `sub my_encode_json { JSON::XS->new->ascii->encode($_[0]) }`

Answer (score 3):

```
use JSON::XS ();
use JSON; # uses JSON::XS by default (if available)
$json_text = to_json( { text => 'Dragón' }, { 'ascii' => 1 } );
```

Comment: JSON loads JSON::PP by default. It only loads JSON::XS if you take the steps to install it. If you want your script to use JSON::XS by default, it has to use it explicitly because `cpan` doesn't support a means to specify "recommended dependencies".

Comment: no, it loads JSON::XS by default.  if that fails, it falls back.  but I will clarify.

Comment: "falls back to JSON::PP" is synonymous with "defaults to JSON::PP". "default: (of a computer program or other mechanism) revert automatically to (a preselected option)."

Comment: that definition misuses "revert", and what it does is revert to PP.  but in any case, if you do not specify PP via the environment variable, it "reverts" to XS (if available).  so even with that broken definition, XS is the default (as is PP).

Comment: absolutely not.  revert is a change from one thing to another.  default is an initial assumption, subject to change.  at least in my version of English.

Comment: in perl code, my definition of default: `sub foo { my %args = ( 'bar' => 42, @_ ) }`, yours (AIUI): `sub foo { my %args = @_; $args{'bar'} = 42 unless exists $args{'bar'} }`.

Comment: no.  but I am saying it defaults to XS under both definitions, and defaults to PP only under yours.

Comment: meh.  the dictionary you (and google) cite is overly influenced by the financial meaning of "default".  the software meaning is completely different.

Comment: no, that is merely to explicitly make it a dependency of the script.  the code behaves the same without (assuming JSON::XS is installed).  You appear to be agreeing with my definition of default now, though...

Comment: Wikipedia and I disagree as well. The hardcoded value is the default. It's what have to you override if you want something different (e.g. You did this by adding `use JSON::XS;` and/or doing `cpan JSON::XS`.)

Comment: no, I sensibly just did `apt-get install libjson-perl` (and got the recommended libjson-xs-perl automatically)

Comment: I so wish you could specify recommended "dependencies" in the META files. I tried to make it happen with little luck.

Comment: you can.  it comes directly from http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.90/META.json / META.yml

Comment: It's not in the META spec (or at least it wasn't then, which was about a year ago), and it's not supported by Module::Build. Don't know about ExtUtils::MakeMaker, `cpan` and `cpanm`.

Comment: Ah good, but useless as even the latest `cpan` completely ignores it.